# Push and splice into array when checkall and checkbox is checked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to push and splice the elements based on checkall, single checkbox clicked, my problem is I am getting a list from angularjs post request and displayed it using `ng-repeat` I have given provision to enter some text in a new column along with `ng-repeat` data. Now based on the user selection of checkall or single checkbox clicked I am pushing the data into array. Here I am able to push the data when the user clicked on single checkbox, but when the user clicked on chekall checkbox 0, 1 are pushing the array instead of textbox value. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Html

```html
<table class='reportstd' align='center' width='80%'>
  <tr class='trdesign'>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="all" data-ng-model="checkedAll" data-ng-change="toggleCheckAll()" />
    </td>
    <td> Sl No</td>
    <td> RO No.</td>
    <td> Truck No.</td>
  </tr>


  <tr data-ng-repeat="user in  RosList">
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.do_ro_no}}" data-ng-model="user.checked" data-ng-change="modifyArrayToPost(user,truck_no[$index])" /> </td>
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{user.do_ro_no}}</td>
    <td><input type='text' data-ng-model="truck_no[$index]" id="truck_no_{{$index}}" name="truck_no_{{$index}}" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name='sea' value='Search' data-ng-submit="postROs(arrayToPost)" /></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Angularjs

```js
$scope.arrayToPost = [];
$scope.toggleCheckAll = function() {
  if ($scope.checkedAll) {
    angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
      user.checked = true;
      $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, truckno);
    });
  } else {
    angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
      user.checked = false;
      $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, truckno);
    });
  }
}

$scope.modifyArrayToPost = function(user, truckno) {

  if (user.checked && truckno != null && $scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.do_ro_no) == -1) {
    $scope.arrayToPost.push(user.do_ro_no, truckno);
  } else if (!user.checked) {
    $scope.arrayToPost.splice($scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.do_ro_no, truckno), 2);
  }
}
$scope.$watch('RosList', function() {
  var allSet = true;
  var allClear = true;
  angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
    if (user.checked) {
      allClear = false;
    } else {
      allSet = false;
    }
  });

  var checkAll = $element.find('#all');
  checkAll.prop('indeterminate', false);
  if (allSet) {
    $scope.checkedAll = true;
  } else if (allClear) {
    $scope.checkedAll = false;
  } else {
    $scope.checkedAll = false;
    checkAll.prop('indeterminate', true);
  }
}, true);
```

```js
$scope.RosList = [
  {do_ro_no: "217PALV000201898", slno: 1, },
  {do_ro_no: "317PALV000201898", slno: 2, }
]
```

**truck_no model is not coming from RosList.**

Comment: Can you add the value of `$scope.RosList` ?

Comment: 0:"{do_ro_no: "217PALV000201898",  slno: 1, }
1:"{do_ro_no: "317PALV000201898",  slno: 2, }

Comment: Dear @Fraction, data-ng-model="truck_no[$index]" is not coming from $scope.RosList.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `truck_no` in your controller as `$scope.truck_no = []` in order to access the values, and in your `$scope.toggleCheckAll` function change `$scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, truckno);` to `$scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, $scope.truck_no[truckno]);`

**EDIT**:
I've slightly modified your code to handle all cases.

Demo: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DnzsCFkPQU8ByFZ8

Comment: Dear @Fraction, when I uncheck the checkbox it's not working.

Comment: @BharathPateru I've updated the demo, now it handles all cases

Comment: Dear @Fraction,   $scope.arrayToPost = [ ...arrToPost ]; what is this do, when I remove this line not working, when I have this line in my code it's showing syntactical error.

Comment: This is [ES6 Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals), only internet explorer doesn't support it, I used it to copy the content of `arrToPost` in `$scope.arrayToPost`, you can replace it by `$scope.arrayToPost = arrToPost ;`

Comment: yes I understood and used it as $scope.arrayToPost = arrToPost, When I print the array I am geeting like this array: ["217PALV000201898","23424","317PALV000202012","3454456"] but I want to store them like this array: [["217PALV000201898","23424"],["317PALV000202012","3454456"]], to differentiating  rows.

Comment: check the new demo

Comment: Dear @Fraction, can you push them into multiple arrays like [217PALV000201898, 317PALV000201898],[1,2],[T123, T456]

Comment: You can initialize the `arrToPost` array as `const arrToPost = [[], [], []];` then push the values: `arrToPost[0].push(user.do_ro_no); arrToPost[1].push(truckno); arrToPost[2].push($scope.truck_no[truckno]);` [more about Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, I think that the solution is much simpler. The main confusation is that there is not just only one "source of truth" - you hold a state for each row and **also** all the `do_ro_no's`.

I suggest to keep track only for each row and calculate the `arrayToPost` whenever you need.

Like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ($scope, $element) => {
  $scope.truck_no = [];
  $scope.RosList = [{
      do_ro_no: "217PALV000201898",
      slno: 1,
    },
    {
      do_ro_no: "317PALV000201898",
      slno: 2,
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.getTruckNo = () => {
    return $scope.truck_no.filter((t, index) => {
      return $scope.RosList[index].checked;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.getArrayToPost = () => {
    return $scope.RosList
      .filter(ros => ros.checked)
      .map(ros => ros.do_ro_no);
  }
  $scope.arrayToPost = [];
  $scope.toggleCheckAll = function() {
    if ($scope.checkedAll) {
      //angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
      //  user.checked = true;
      //  $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, truckno);
      //});
      $scope.RosList.forEach(ros => ros.checked = true);
    } else {
      //angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
      //  user.checked = false;
      //  $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user, truckno);
      //});
      
      $scope.RosList.forEach(ros => ros.checked = false);
    }
  }

  //$scope.modifyArrayToPost = function(user, truckno) {
  //  if (user.checked && truckno != null && $scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.do_ro_no) == -1) {
  //    $scope.arrayToPost.push(user.do_ro_no, truckno);
  //  } else if (!user.checked) {
  //    $scope.arrayToPost.splice($scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.do_ro_no, truckno), 2);
  //  }
  //}

  //$scope.$watch('RosList', function() {
  //  var allSet = true;
  //  var allClear = true;
  //  angular.forEach($scope.RosList, function(user, truckno) {
  //    if (user.checked) {
  //      allClear = false;
  //    } else {
  //      allSet = false;
  //    }
  //  });
//
  //  var checkAll = $element.find('#all');
  //  checkAll.prop('indeterminate', false);
  //  if (allSet) {
  //    $scope.checkedAll = true;
  //  } else if (allClear) {
  //    $scope.checkedAll = false;
  //  } else {
  //    $scope.checkedAll = false;
  //    checkAll.prop('indeterminate', true);
  //  }
  //}, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class='reportstd' align='center' width='80%'>
    <tr class='trdesign'>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="all" data-ng-model="checkedAll" data-ng-change="toggleCheckAll()" />
      </td>
      <td> Sl No</td>
      <td> RO No.</td>
      <td> Truck No.</td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-ng-repeat="user in  RosList">
      <td> <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.do_ro_no}}" data-ng-model="user.checked" data-ng-change="modifyArrayToPost(user,truck_no[$index])" /> </td>
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{user.do_ro_no}}</td>
      <td><input type='text' data-ng-model="truck_no[$index]" id="truck_no_{{$index}}" name="truck_no_{{$index}}" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'><input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name='sea' value='Search' data-ng-submit="postROs(arrayToPost)" /></td>

    </tr>
  </table>

  <pre>
    {{getTruckNo() | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

The array is the result of `getTruckNo()` as you can see in the snippet.

Comment: Dear @Mosh Feu I want to store text box values into array and when a check box unchecked i want to remove the checked row details (do_ro_no, text box) from the array.